# centos 7 virtualbox no internet, how to get rid of virbr0 and virbr0-nic adapters?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat, centos-7

I have tried everything. I have 2 hosts and 2 centos 7 virtual machines with nat connection and wireless internet. The first has only lo and enp0s3 adapters and everything is fine. The second has lo, enp0s3, virbr0 and virbr0-nic adapters and it cannot ping. How can get rid of these two adapters or how can make it connect to internet?

Comment: nm-connection-editor  and  delete them maybe?  What  HyperV you using  exactly that  also matters.

Comment: Hyper-V Manager Version 6.1.7601.17514

Comment: What is the command for the nm-connection editor?